# What is the purpose of the firebase-admin SDK if you cannot use it on client side?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I was thinking about how can I use the firebase-admin SDK to perform privileged operations from my client side app beyond the rules I wrote for regular users, how can I invoke/call the methods and functions that this SDK provides from my client admin side app/website?

I mean I want to make a web app to my users with a completely different UI and another in a subdomain for example (admin.myapp.com) where I can make use of the admin sdk, but if lets say that in my app hosted in (myapp.com) I have a login/signup form where users can register and login using the regular firebase client sdk, now for example if in my admin website I have the same form, regular signed in users can also login in my admin website which is not what I want since only me and nobody else can enter in this website.

How can I separated my website app from my admin website?

**Somebody can explain to me what is the purpose of the firebase admin-sdk? and how should be used it and how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) is meant to be used on your server, not in the client.  That's why the title of that page is "Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server".  It isn't intended for use in apps that ship to end users.  If you want a user to execute some privileged code, they should be making calls through your server.

Comment: I know what It is the point here is how do I have two separated UI one for regular users and one for admin users? I mean its kind like WordPress you can have yourdomain.com and at the same time have yourdomain.com/wp-login.php a completely different UI. If I have the admin user as a regular email and password like any other regular resgitered user they can also get in my admin page/website/whatever do you understand? I need to have separated UI where my admin don't collide with my users...

Comment: Splitting the functionality of your app between admin type users and regular type users doesn't really have anything to do with the admin SDK.  You just need to build your app in a way to respects the privileges of those types of users.  If you don't have a backend, then you don't need the admin SDK.